# FFMPEG output file does not contain any stream [Android] video concat

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have been trying to merge (concatenate) two mp4 videos with same height and width but some error occurs. It says the output file doesnot have any stream.
Please help.
The code is written below :

```
String[] arg = new String[]{
                ActualVideoFile.getAbsolutePath(), path
        };
        String list = generateList(arg);
        String[] command = new String[]{
                " -f concat -i " + list + " -c:v copy " + mergedVideo.getAbsolutePath()
        };
        try {
            ffmpeg.execute(command, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.e("SUCCESS", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
                    Log.e("onProgress", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e("onFailure", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("onStart", "start");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.e("FINISH", "FINISHED");

                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Logcat:

```
E/onFailure: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                            built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                            configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                            libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                            libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                            libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                            libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                            libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                            libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                            libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                            libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                          Output #0, mp4, to ' -f concat -i /data/data/com.myapp/cache/ffmpeg-list-768575373.txt -c:v copy /storage/emulated/0/myapp/MergedVideos/1465426928071_Video.mp4':
                                                          Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Dunno if it will fix but try... `"-y -f concat -i " + list + " -c:v copy -map 0" + mergedVideo.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: see this link https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/88 it might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is my complete code snippet.. I am adding image overlay to video. For testing I have kept video and image in assets folder

```
    File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EditedVideo_2/");
    File outputDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EditedVideo_2/video" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");



    Log.d("directory path",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EditedVideo_2/");


    if (!myDirectory.exists())
    {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EditedVideo_2/sample.mp4");
    if (!f.exists()) try
    {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("sample.mp4");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


    Log.d("Path = ",f.getPath());



   File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EditedVideo_2/ic_launcher.png");
    if (!imageFile.exists()) try
    {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }




    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);


    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler()
        {

            @Override
            public void onStart()
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure()
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onFailure");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onSuccess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onFinish");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
    }





    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        //String[] cmd = {"-version"};



        String[] cmd = {"-i",""+f.getPath(),"-i",""+imageFile.getPath(),"-filter_complex","overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10",outputDirectory.getPath()};
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler()
        {

            @Override
            public void onStart()
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message)
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onProgress - "+message);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message)
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onFailure - "+message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message)
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onSuccess - "+message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                Log.d("Event ","onFinish");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
```

Comment: you really saved my day

Comment: Thanks buddy, saved the day

Comment: Please what is the command for combining two videos instead of putting an image on top of the video?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Turns out it's how the command is built.

This is incorrect as you need to divide up each command:

```
String[] command = new String[]{" -f concat -i " + list + " -c:v copy " + mergedVideo.getAbsolutePath();
```

Chirag your answer is spot on:

```
String[] cmd = {"-i",""+f.getPath(),"-i",""+imageFile.getPath(),"-filter_complex","overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10",outputDirectory.getPath()};
```

Hope this helps.